# Gridview change datasource embed in custom control

Tags: c#, gridview, custom-server-controls

I have a gridview rendered in custom server composite control in c#.net. I want to dynamically change the datasource of gridview from the Web Application which is using this DLL contol. Any ideas of how to achive this???